# No location permission pop up for locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm following an online tutorial to make a simple project that displays a user's location on the map. However, when I run it, the user location is not displayed and there is no pop up to ask for location permission. I'm not sure how I can fix that. I've attached the code below.

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel=ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onAppear{viewModel.checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()}
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

final class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:37.3331516, longitude: -121.891054), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1));
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled(){
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager=CLLocationManager()
            locationManager!.delegate=self
        }
        else{
            print("Turn location on")
        }
    }
    private func checkLocationAuthorization(){
        guard let locationManager = locationManager else {
            return
        }
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus{
        case.notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Your location is restricted likely due to parental controls.")
        case .denied:
            print("You have denied this app location permission. Go into settings to change it.")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            region=MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span:MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            region=MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span:MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
        func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_manager: CLLocationManager) {
            checkLocationAuthorization()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was tasked to review this as a first question. I let it stand, but please goggle your question before posting here. The location permission popup question has been asked and answered many, many times...

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 issues

1. You are not asking for permissions.
2. You implemented the delegate wrong.

This should work:

```
final class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:37.3331516, longitude: -121.891054), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1));
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
   
    func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled(){
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager=CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate=self
            //ask for permissions here
            //depending on your usage you could also ask for 
            //locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        else{
            print("Turn location on")
        }
    }
    private func checkLocationAuthorization(){
        guard let locationManager = locationManager else {
            return
        }
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus{
        case.notDetermined:
            //the function containing this will only be called if the permission get requested so remove it
            //locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Your location is restricted likely due to parental controls.")
        case .denied:
            print("You have denied this app location permission. Go into settings to change it.")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            region=MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span:MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            region=MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span:MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    // this function was wrapped inside your checkLocationAuthorization() function
    //move it to outer scope. It gets called every time you request permissions
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
        
    }
}
```

Be aware you will have to add multiple privacy keys to get this working.